# How to make a Java class accessable within the same library only (in Java 8)

Tags: java

Consider the below example as my class library project, I need to make `CommonClass` accessable for all other classes in the same project (A, B and C) but not accessable to the world (when using the library by another projects), where `CommonClass` contains common methods and fields that are used by all other classes within my library, in **C#** this is solved by using the `internal` access modifier on `CommonClass`. Is this even possible using **Java**?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an excellent use-case for [Java 9's module system](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/modular-development). With it, you can export all packages except for `com.test.pac4`, prohibiting any project that depends on your library from accessing any classes within that package (unless your users override it via `--add-exports`).

To do this, you can create a `module-info.java` file in your source directory that contains the following (I recommend changing the module name):

```
module com.test.project {
    exports com.test.pac1;
    exports com.test.pac2;
    exports com.test.pac3;
}
```

You'll also need to use `requires` for any modules that your project depends on (see: [Java 9 Modularity](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity)).

---

If you're using Java 8 or below, then the above solution isn't possible, as the module system was introduced in Java 9.

One workaround on Java 8 is to modify your project hierarchy; you can move every class that accesses `CommonClass` into a single package, and then make `CommonClass` package-private. This will prevent your library's users from being able to access `CommonClass`.

Comment: but this is only added in java 9, now I'm still using Java 8 and I can't upgrade for many reasons

Comment: @peterbence That's unfortunate. A Java 8 solution would be to move all of your classes into a single package, and make `CommonClass` package-private.

Comment: please add this to your answer (That this is not possible in java 8) to mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @peterbence Good suggestion, I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is assumed that you want to restrict access of class com.sunilos.SecureClass outside your project. It is assumed that base package of your project is "com.sunilos" then you can introduce following code in your class constructor:

```
public class SecureClass {

final String BASE_PKG = "com.sunilos";

public SecureClass() {
    StackTraceElement[] stElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (int i = 1; i < stElements.length; i++) {
        StackTraceElement ste = stElements[i];
        if (!ste.getClassName().startsWith(BASE_PKG)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Security Issue");
        }
    }
}

public String status() {
    return "live";
   }

}
```

It will restrict access of your class outside the base package com.sunilos .